# Trouble with setting up an hierarchy object following asynchronous calls

Tags: angular, typescript, object, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to create a category hierarchy from some categories we have stored in the database. The thing is that we are getting the information from different tables: we have one method to get all the information relating the Categories and then another one that has the ParentChild data stored with just the parentCategoryId and childCategoryId fields, where we can see the relationship between them.

There is no information related to the kinship in the Category object, so I am trying to get by using what we got. So this far, this is what I got:

```
    const categoryMap = {};

    categories.forEach((category) => {
      const id = category.id;

      this.categoryService
        .getParentChildCategories(category.id)
        .subscribe((childCategories) => {
          const isParent = childCategories.length > 0;
          if (isParent) {
            this.secondLevelCategories.push(category);
            childCategories.map((childCategory) => {
              this.categoryService
                .getParentChildCategories(childCategory.id)
                .subscribe((grandchildCategories) => {
                  const isGrandparent = grandchildCategories.length > 0;
                  const childId = childCategory.id;
                  if (isGrandparent) {
                    this.firstLevelCategories.push(category);
                    categoryMap[id] = { ...category, children: [], parentId: null };

                    categoryMap[id].children[childId] = {
                      ...childCategory,
                      children: [],
                      parentId: id,
                    };

                    grandchildCategories.forEach((grandchildCategory) => {
                      categoryMap[category.id].children[childId].children.push(
                        grandchildCategory
                      );
                      grandchildCategory.parentId = childId;
                      this.thirdLevelCategories.push(grandchildCategory)
                    });
                  } else {
                    categoryMap[id] = { ...category, children: [] };
                  }
                });
            });
          } else {
            categoryMap[id] = { ...category, children: [] };
            //this.firstLevelCategories.push(category)
          }
          console.log(categoryMap)
        });
    });

    return categoryMap;
  }
```

So, we start passing the categories object as a paramater, which we get from the CategoryService that uses a http get call to get all the categories data.

Then, for each category we use the getParentChildCategories call that checks the second table mentioned earlier and gets as a response the childCategories that have the category evaluated as parentCategory.

We have created a categoryMap object in order to map this hierarchy and further utilise it on the front-end.

For the childCategories, we will execute on them the getParentChild method in order to check if they have anymore child categories. If this is the case, we will start the mapping by creating the category.id object, push it's child categories and finally it's grandchild categories to the correspondant childCategory.

Until here, everything is going well. But then, there is some asynchrony issue because I am not able to access the categoryMap data outside the last if section, so I need to manipulate the data inside it. But I am not able to figure out how.

At the moment, I have been able to map the child and grandchild categories for a category that does have both but I haven't figured out how to sort the rest. As a matter of fact, the grandchild categories are getting populated as parent categories as well as it is happening for the other child categories from the parent category.

I am sharing the object I am getting for some reference:

```
    "1084": {
        "id": 1084,
        "name": "DummyCorp",
        "description": "Dummy Corporation",
        "color": "#abcdef",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 17,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": null,
        "children": [
            null,
            null,
            {
                "id": 1087,
                "name": "Tools",
                "description": "Tools",
                "color": "#123456",
                "hidden": false,
                "isFavorite": false,
                "reportCount": 0,
                "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
                "image": "dummy-image-url",
                "order": 1,
                "parentId": 1084,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 1092,
                        "name": "Marketing",
                        "description": "Marketing",
                        "color": "#789012",
                        "hidden": false,
                        "isFavorite": false,
                        "reportCount": 0,
                        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
                        "image": "dummy-image-url",
                        "order": 1,
                        "parentId": 1087
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1099,
                        "name": "NuevaCat",
                        "description": "NuevaCat",
                        "color": "#345678",
                        "hidden": false,
                        "isFavorite": false,
                        "reportCount": 0,
                        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
                        "image": "dummy-image-url",
                        "order": 1,
                        "parentId": 1087
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1088,
                        "name": "Zebra BI",
                        "description": "Zebra BI",
                        "color": "#901234",
                        "hidden": false,
                        "isFavorite": false,
                        "reportCount": 0,
                        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
                        "image": "dummy-image-url",
                        "order": 1,
                        "parentId": 1087
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "1085": {
        "id": 1085,
        "name": "Customers",
        "description": "Customers",
        "color": "#fedcba",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 6,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1086": {
        "id": 1086,
        "name": "Financial",
        "description": "Financial",
        "color": "#abcdef",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 2,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1087": {
        "id": 1087,
        "name": "Tools",
        "description": "Tools",
        "color": "#123456",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 5,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1088": {
        "id": 1088,
        "name": "Zebra BI",
        "description": "Zebra BI",
        "color": "#901234",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 3,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1092": {
        "id": 1092,
        "name": "Marketing",
        "description": "Marketing",
        "color": "#789012",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 0,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1096": {
        "id": 1096,
        "name": "Paginated ",
        "description": "Paginated ",
        "color": "#abcdef",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 5,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1097": {
        "id": 1097,
        "name": "Enric Category",
        "description": "Enric Category",
        "color": "#fedcba",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 1,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1098": {
        "id": 1098,
        "name": "Mapa",
        "description": "Nueva cat",
        "color": "#abcdef",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 0,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1099": {
        "id": 1099,
        "name": "NuevaCat",
        "description": "NuevaCat",
        "color": "#345678",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 1,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    },
    "1100": {
        "id": 1100,
        "name": "Test Category",
        "description": "Test",
        "color": "#abcdef",
        "hidden": false,
        "isFavorite": false,
        "reportCount": 0,
        "organizationId": "dummy-org-id-123",
        "image": "dummy-image-url",
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": []
    }
}
```

So, I am out of ideas. Is there someone that can give some insight about working with asynchronous data and object mapping?

I already tried ChatGPT 3,5 but it is clueless.

I tried everything but cannot find the way. I know that it would be simpler to modify the table for Categories but wanted to try doing it with less resources.